# Filter LINQ entity include query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following two tables

```
Groups
Id (int)

People
Id (int)
GroupId (int, Groups.Id)
IsSelected (bit)
```

This will return all Groups with all their members(People) in a single query

```
var grps = myDatabase.Groups.Include("People");
```

How can I write a single query that will return all Groups with People who has been selected(IsSelected = true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this works

```
    var grps = myDatabase.Groups.Select(g=> new { g, people = g.People.Where(p=>p.IsSelected)});
```

Comment: In LINQ to SQL, you could use the DataLoadOptions.LoadWith to add the additional filtering. With EF, you are relegated to a subselect as this example provides.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the 'join' method, like this:

```
(from g in myDatabase.Groups
 join p in myDatabase.People on g.Id equals p.GroupId
 where p.IsSelected == true
 select g);
```

This will give you all groups where there are people selected.

Comment: this will return only groups with selected people. it should return ALL groups regardless of whether they contain people, but if they contain people then only include selected people

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score -1):

OR check out .Where()

Something like

```
var grps = myDatabase.Groups.Include("People").Where(x => x.IsSelected); 
//x => !x.IsSelected for false
```

Comment: This is just wiggling the syntax around in hope it starts to work by coincidence.

Comment: well, no, I was merely suggesting .where() as a way to filter, per the question.  "Something like" -as a pointer to figure it out.  But fair enough it was sloppy to copy and paste OP statement and just stick it on the end.  I was bad.